# Delayed Dialog Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to delay the pop of a Dialog in Java. **I don't want to use Thread.sleep because animations are being played meanwhile.**

Here is what I've tried, but it is not working:

```
try{
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.wait(1500);
    d.show();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

The Dialog isn't showing. However, when I remove the `d.wait(1500)`then it works.

Do you have any idea to help me?

Thank you!

Comment: use handler for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform something after a delay on Android use a Handler and it's postDelayed method. It takes a runnable which defines the code to be run and an int which defines the delay before that runnable is executed.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final Dialog d = new Dialog(getContext());
                            d.show();
                        }
                    }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Handler with postDelay() method, here is the code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Dialog d = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
            d.show();
        }
    }, 1000);
```